# Remove decimal point and numbers from string in Android

Tags: android, parsing, rounding

So, I have two numbers as strings - for example, 123.00 and 123.50.  How do I remove the decimal point and all that follows.  I had a method that worked for the 123.00, but would not work correctly on the 123.50.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    String balance = getString("balance");

    BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(balance);

    String formattedBalance = number.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();

    int roundedBalance = Integer.parseInt(formattedBalance);
```

Comment: you have to split the string and use 1st string value Split with "."

Answer (score 0):

```
int roundedBalance = Integer.parseInt(getString("balance").split(".")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove the following points or numbers?

If only the points why not:

```
balance = balance.replace(".","");
```

Comment: I wanted to remove the points and number.